# Naming vs nomenclature

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I think [naming](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) should be a synonym of [nomenclature](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature). What do you think?

Comment: I think nomenclature should be a synonym of naming! Naming is by far the more common word. I'd never heard of nomenclature until a couple of weeks ago when someone tagged it here.

Comment: @Liam nomenclature is definitely the more formal word which is why I prefer it. Go ahead and post your comment as an answer. The most important thing in my opinion is one is a synonym not which one is the primary

Comment: I'm confused by this. Is this common? It's certainly not common in UK english.

Comment: @Liam it feels fairly common to me in the US. It was fairly common at my job in the Marines and fairly common in technical docs. In nontechnical arenas it much less common. I might be an outlier though

Comment: @Liam I can chime in with an example from Canada at work we have a naming convention for our servers or we refer to it as our server nomenclature, both are interchangeable and even Wikipedia is suggesting to merge the pages...

Comment: In fairness, no one right now can make this change anyway. You need a score of at least 5 or more to nominate a synonym. It then requires several (can't remember exactly how many) up votes by similar people. No one participating in this discussion meets these requirements..

Comment: @Liam a mod can make it or the tags could just be adjusted so one tag dies

Comment: I don't think the mods really get involved. It's not actually that important, especially being as their is only 2 questions involved. The easiest way is to re-tag them. Then the tag without any questions just dies when the bot cleans them up. Though beware not to get drawn into a *tagging war* with someone

Comment: @Liam I agree on all counts. This Meta question is an attempt to draw consensus and hopefully avoid a tag war.

Comment: Agree, just saying really. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though nomenclature includes naming, but not vice versa, **I prefer naming**. The purpose of the tags is to aid the user, and naming will be more helpful than a word someone has to look up. I agree that combining the two is a good idea.

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nomenclature), **nomenclature**:

> 1 :   name, designation
>
> 2 :   the act or process or an instance of naming
>
> 3a:   a system or set of terms or symbols especially in a particular
>   science, discipline, or art
>
> 3b:   an international system of standardized New Latin names used in
>   biology for kinds and groups of kinds of animals and plants

Definition of **naming**, from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/naming) Examples are for named, but they can all be converted to naming, e.g., I am naming the baby Susan.

> verb (used with object), named, naming.
>
> to give a name to: to name a baby.
>
> to accuse: He was named as the thief.
>
> to call by an epithet: They named her speedy.
>
> to identify, specify, or mention by name:Three persons were named in
>   the report.
>
> to designate for some duty or office; nominate or appoint: I have
>   named you for the position.
>
> to specify; suggest: Name a price.
>
> to give the name of: Can you name the capital of Ohio

Comment: Personally I prefer nomenclature because the top two definitions for it seem to mean exactly what the tag is about. The need to look up the definition seems mitigated by hovering over the tag. The tags summary, visible when hovering, should be enough to let people know the purpose of the tag. All that being said so far we have two answers supporting naming so it appears as if I'm in the minority. :)

Answer (score 7):

I think their might be a cultural battle here. I personally have never heard the term [nomenclature](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) and I certainly don't use it (at all, let alone reguarly).

For me the more common term is [naming](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) so this should be the master.

Answer (score 4):

[naming](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) should be a synonym of [nomenclature](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature).

Comment: @erik I can't upvote my own answer so I guess that would make it four. :-)